# JavaScript - Why does my asrnchronous download not download asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, asynchronous

I'm using the following Google Maps autload (asynchronous) to load asynchronous both Google Maps v3 and JQuery, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={ "modules":[ {name:"maps",version:3,other_params:"sensor=false"},{"name":"jquery","version":"1.4.2"},{"name":"jqueryui","version":"1.8.1"} ]}"></script>
```

However, looking at the network traffic, it appears that it is not downloading asynchronously.

[alt text http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/5986/jquerydelaying.png](http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/5986/jquerydelaying.png)

**Question**: Does anyone understand why the `%7Bcommon` (google-maps) file is being delayed from download until the `jquery-ui.min` file completes download first?

Comment: Isn't the browser going to limit the number of concurrent TCP connections?

Comment: @Pointy Modern browsers have a limit of 6 concurrent connections, so that's not the problem. My guess is that the reason is that animated-loading-ic... image. Maybe you should try loading the scripts after that image?

Comment: @Pointy, That doesn't seem to apply. Because at the point of *%7Bcommon*, the only two open connections are *jquery-ui.min* and *main.js* - which are on different domains. So unless the concurrent TCP connections limit from a single domain is ONE, this would not be the reason for the blocking in download of *%7Bcommon*.

Comment: @juandopazo, it's my understanding that graphics don't block TCP connections ... only JavaScript. As such, the *animated-loading-icon.gif* would not be the reason.

Comment: Yup. It was just a wild guess. If I manage to get a test case working that explains it, I'll let you know.

Comment: Wild guess: Does main.js have a dependency on jQuery?